# python comprehension for loop with if statement and other actions following that

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
if n,item in enumerate(list):
    if item=='pattern':
        dict[item]=[] #basically I need a step to initialize the value of that dictionary as a list.
    dict[item].append(n)
```

Once dict has each key with a value as list, I could append things of interest related to item to that list(In this case just the iteration number n).

How to make a comprehension does the same thing?

Comment: You don't want a comprehension for this... It's not what they were made for.  It _looks_ like you want to be using a `collections.defaultdict`, but it's hard to say.  What do you want to have happen if `item == 'argyle'`?

Comment: @mgilson yes defaultdict will do this. Above I was just asking if I could use comprehension to create that dict with value as lists which involves a 'if statement' . Use defaultdict there is no need for that 'if'. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for index, key in enumerate(l):
    if key == "pattern":
        d[key].append(index)
```

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ["test1", "pattern", "test2", "pattern"]

d = defaultdict(list)
for index, key in enumerate(l):
    if key == "pattern":
        d[key].append(index)

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'pattern': [1, 3]}
```

Comment: Maybe ... though it seems like `d = {'pattern': [ix for ix, key in enumerate(l) if key == 'pattern']}` would be easier . . . Now if OP wants a map of "keys" to indices -- _then_ a `defaultdict` would shine. . .

Comment: @mgilson yeah, good point. I think you should post it as an answer. Though, it is not completely clear what the use case is. Thanks.

Comment: You changed the functionality, though. A lot.

Comment: @StefanPochmann -- Maybe.  With the way it's written, OP's code looks like it will frequently be raising `KeyError` or `TypeError` -- It's hard to know if alecxe changed the desired functionality or implemented it (which happens somewhat frequently with unclear questions like this . . .)